# Prove that $f^{-1}(I)=\{x\in R \mid f(x)\in I\}$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: ring-theory

Assume $f:R\to S$ be a homomorphism

(i.e. $x,y\in R \text{ then } f(xy)=f(x)(y)$),

and $I$ an ideal of $S$.

(i.e. (1) $I$ is a subgroup of $S$ under addition, (2) for any $x \in R$, $xI=\{xy\mid y\in I\}$).

Prove that $f^{-1}(I)=\{x\in R\mid f(x)\in I\}$ is an ideal of $R$.

Proof: Assume $x,y\in f^{-1}(I)$, then $f(x),f(y)\in I$. 
Similarly, assume $x\cdot y\in f^{-1}(I)$, then $f(x\cdot y)\in I$. Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$. Since $I$ is an ideal, $f(x)f(y)\in I$.

So this is a proof I found online. My questions are (1) how did they know to start the proof as they did? and (2) How do I continue on from here?

Comment: This (part if) proof is wrong: only one of $x,y$ has to be supposed in $f^{-1}(I)$. Once you've given the correct proof for multiplication, you do the same for addition.

Comment: you are using two symbols: $\Bbb R$ and $R$, are they the same?

Comment: @janmarqz Sorry I meant $R$

Comment: @Bernard What is part if? Why only one of $x,y$ needs to be in $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped *part of*. For your second question, it's in the definition of an ideal: the product of an element of the ideal by any element of the ring must be in the ideal.

Comment: Why can't the product of two elements of the ideal be in the ideal?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown, you can, but, that isn't needed in the ideal's definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in R$ and $y\in f^{–1}(I)$ be, then $f(y)\in I$. But $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ then $f(xy)\in I$, and hence $xy\in f^{-1}(I)$. This complete the proof of the claim.

Comment: Ok. I agree with all the logic in the proof expect for one part. Why start the proof like this? It seems that we are starting from the stand point that we are showing that it only has the absorption property. How do we know this is a subgroup of R.

Comment: that's easy: If $a,b\in f^{-1}(I)$ then $f(a),f(b)\in I$, so $f(a)-f(b)\in I$ but $f(a)-f(b)=f(a-b)$, then $f(a-b)\in I$ and hence $a-b\in f^{-1}(I)$

Comment: Why did you use subtraction? Could you have done the same thing with addition?

Comment: there is a Lemma that reads "A set $H\subset G$ of a group is a subgroup if an only if $x-y\in H$ for all $x,y\in H$". I think that this is known as the **subgroup criterion** (written additively).

Comment: and yes, you could do it with the sum

Comment: Ah! ok, you are welcome : )

Answer (score 0):

For a given $f\colon R \to S$ one can define a homomorphism $\tilde f\colon R \to S/I$ which sends $r \in R$ to $f(r) + I$.  The kernel of $\tilde f$ is precisely those elements whose image under $f$ is in the ideal $I$, thus $\ker \tilde f = f^{-1}(I)$.  Since $f^{-1}(I)$ is the kernel of a homomorphism from $R$, this shows that $f^{-1}(I)$ is an ideal of $R$.

If you're skeptical of the last step, let $h\colon R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism (with $R$ and $S$ not necessarily the same as in the previous paragraph) and let $x_1$ and $x_2 \in \ker h$ and $r \in R$.  Then $h(x_1 + x_2) = h(x_1) + h(x_2) = 0$, $h(r x_1) = h(r) h(x_1) = h(r) \cdot 0 = 0$ and likewise $h(x_1 r) = 0$.